# The property 'Lead' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.ProjectsListListItem'. Error in Sharepint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, crud

I have developed Sharepoint Hosted Addin with a List called Projects. And It has a Lookup for another List called Users to get the Team Lead for that project. When I trying to add new List Item to the Logs list using CRUD APIs and Sharepoint Hosted Addin, It gives this error.

```
The property 'Lead' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.ProjectsListListItem'. 
Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type when using 
lookups
```

I searched lot in there documentations and haven't found a solution. Can anyone help me to go through this error. Thank you.

This is the AJAX call I use to send the data to list,

```
function addLog(data, formDigest) {
    var url = appUrl + listUrl + "/Items";
    url = GoodT.Repositories.targetUrl(url, hostUrl);

    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": formDigest
        }
    });

    return call;
}
```

Comment: can you share the sample code/ code snippet that you are using ?

Comment: @Sandun Make sure list identity name is correcnt i.e. SP.Data.ProjectsListListItem which can be verify by /_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('List Name')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName

Comment: Yeh, It's correct. But I have given this error. @ShridharJJoshi

Comment: I have tried changing the Listnames also. But didn't worked. This is worked fine before I delete my List accidentally.

Comment: @sandun lead is internal name?

Comment: What do you mean as internal @ShridharJJoshi

Comment: Internalname of the list field/column

Comment: Yeh It is same...

Comment: @Sandun can you please share your metadata part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "Lead" is the single lookup/user field, the data structure like this.

```
var data = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.ProjectsListItem" },
    "Title": 'Test',
    'LeadId': 12  //single-valued User field value 
};
```

If the "Lead" is the multiple lookup/user field, the data structure like this.

```
var data = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.ProjectsListItem" },
    "Title": 'Test',
    'LeadId': {"results": [12] }  //multi-valued User field value 
};
```

Comment: Oh Thanks a Lot, This worked for me. Because I have entered values for Leader, not the LeaderId. You have saved my 2 days.